# Why are deleted questions removed from a person's history?

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions, revisions-list

Somebody just posted a rant - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6036325/whats-wrong-with-you. I thought I would check their profile and see what the fuss was about. Problem was, the post they're obviously upset about doesn't seem to be there. And now that the rant was deleted (as it should have been), it's not showing up either. https://stackoverflow.com/users/726359/themonster

I can see why we don't want deleted questions referenced in any of the usual places, but it seems like the user profile should be complete.

P.S. The rant started with a request to close their account, so the links I placed above as an example are probably worthless. The question still stands.

Comment: *Closed* questions do show up. *Deleted* questions don't (except for moderators).

Comment: I edited to replace all "closed" with "deleted", since that is the scenario. In which case, all I can say is... "why are deleted files removed from my file system?" (yet kinda still available)

Comment: @Marc (Gravell) Probably because you favorite OS provider does not sell SSDs yet

Comment: @Wether - I'm on SSD - I still have a recycle bin ;p

Answer (score 2):

As balpha said, deleted questions only appear in the profile to moderators (not 10k users)

10k users can, however, read a deleted question if they have the direct link to them (as they do not appear anywhere)